# Scope or override \pause?

Tags: beamer, align, pause

I have some lecture slides with multi-part problems. I would like for the students to be able to see the entire problem laid out, and then fill in the answers step-by-step. This is doable as long as the stuff that's filling in can be divided up into nice little chunks:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}\onslide<+->{}
This problem has three parts.
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item What is the answer to part 1?\\
      \onslide<+->{First interpret the question.}\onslide<+->{ Then do some work.}\onslide<+->{ Now we can answer the question, and the answer is} \onslide<+->{ 42.}
    \item What is the answer to part 2?\\
      \onslide<+->{This problem is easy, and the answer is }\onslide<+->{0.}
    \item What is the answer to part 3?\\
      \onslide<+->{You'll have to figure this one out for yourself.}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This solution is fairly elegant (except for the initial `\onslide<+->` to increment the counter). Unfortunately, it breaks down (or at least becomes very messy) if I want to pause in the middle of an environment, like an align:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
%% Standard (?) fix to make \pause work at all in align environment
\mode<presentation>{\setbeamercovered{transparent=0}}
\makeatletter
\def\beamerorig@set@color{%
  \pdfliteral{\current@color}%
  \aftergroup\reset@color
}
\def\beamerorig@reset@color{\pdfliteral{\current@color}}
\makeatother
%%

\begin{frame}
This problem has three parts.
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item What is the answer to part 1?\\\pause
      First interpret the question. Then calculate
      \begin{align*}
        \Pr[X\in A] &=\pause \frac{1}{2^n} \sum_{i=0}^n \binom{n}{i} \\ 
        &=\pause 1
      \end{align*}
    \item What is the answer to part 2?\\\pause
      More answers, \pause with more parts.
    \item What is the answer to part 3?\\\pause
      ...
  \end{enumerate}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Of course if I do it this way the later parts of the problem don't show up until after we've finished the first part.

I could probably make the former approach work by breaking up the answer into even smaller chunks and then ensuring that the text before and the first part of the `align` show up simultaneously, but that seems like it would a lot of manual fiddling on a case-by-case basis. I would think that the correct solution would be either to restrict the effect of `\pause` to some scope within the answer itself or to override it by forcing the later material I want visible at the beginning to be opaque (I believe that the fix for `align` already makes it so that the text is always there, just transparent).

Is there a good way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using the following workaround using the (admittedly very hackish) `\always` command which resets the slide counter for its contents:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%% Standard (?) fix to make \pause work at all in align environment
\mode<presentation>{\setbeamercovered{transparent=0}}
\makeatletter
\def\beamerorig@set@color{%
  \pdfliteral{\current@color}%
  \aftergroup\reset@color
}
\def\beamerorig@reset@color{\pdfliteral{\current@color}}
\makeatother
%%

%% \always{} command ensures that its contents are visible on all slides of the frame.
\newcounter{beamerpausessave}
\newcommand{\always}[1]{\setcounter{beamerpausessave}{\value{beamerpauses}}
    \setcounter{beamerpauses}{0}\pause #1 
    \setcounter{beamerpauses}{\value{beamerpausessave}}\addtocounter{beamerpauses}{-1}\pause}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
This problem has three parts.
  \begin{enumerate}
    \always{\item What is the answer to part 1?\\}\pause
      First interpret the question. Then calculate
      \begin{align*}
        \Pr[X\in A] &=\pause \frac{1}{2^n} \sum_{i=0}^n \binom{n}{i} \\ 
        &=\pause 1
      \end{align*}
    \always{\item What is the answer to part 2?\\}\pause
      More answers, \pause with more parts.
    \always{\item What is the answer to part 3?\\}\pause
      ...
  \end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I still don't really understand why that particular combination of setting `beamerpauses` and using `\pause` happened to work when nothing simpler did.